# Align text to center of navbar

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I've created a navbar where I've also added a back button and I want some text in the center of the bar. However I can't seem to figure out how to get the text in center.

Here's my css code:

```
#navbar {
    background: black;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 10px;



}

#navbar > a{
margin-top:2%;
float:left;
}
```

I've also created a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w0sxf3fd/2/

Comment: The `h1` comes with default margin. Set `h1` to `margin: 0`.

Comment: That seemed to solve the problem with it not being in horizontal center but it's still not in vertical center. The button still moves the text to the right, even in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w0sxf3fd/5/

Comment: That works like a charm, however the problem is that this affects the rest of the page that uses the <h1> tag. Would it be possible to add it so it will only affect this particular part?

Comment: Yes. Just target the `h1` in the navbar only: `div#navbar > h1 { ... } `. http://jsfiddle.net/w0sxf3fd/6/